# Writing testable code - a basic_istream factory within lambda functions and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unit-testing, lambda, c++14, boost-program-options

## Introduction

This is a request for an assessment of my approach, in the context of modern C++ features that I'm not confident with yet, like lambda functions and `basic_istream`. I have a short list of specific questions at the end, all of which are related to the same issue.

## Background

I am writing a config file parser in C++14 using `Boost::program_options` (1.69), in particular the `boost::program_options::parse_config_file()` function. This function (defined in `boost/program_options/parsers.hpp`) has two overrides.

The first reads the config from a file on disk:

```
basic_parsed_options<charT>
parse_config_file(const char* filename, const options_description&,
                  bool allow_unregistered = false);
```

The second reads the config from a `std::basic_istream<charT>` reference:

```
basic_parsed_options<charT>
parse_config_file(std::basic_istream<charT>&, const options_description&,
                  bool allow_unregistered = false);
```

I am writing unit tests (using Google Test) so that I can pass the contents of the configuration file to the function, rather than have the test read from an actual file, as it would in production. This is to avoid having to create temporary config files, avoid conflicts when running tests in parallel, etc. Perhaps this approach could be better, but it doesn't seem wrong to have the ability to provide config from a string rather than a file.

I will also add that I cannot simply pass the istream to the `process_config` function because, in the full implementation, the filename is actually determined within the function itself. I.e. the command-line is parsed first, and the config filename is taken from this. Therefore the filename is not known before the function is executed.

## Implementation

The function under test originally looked like this:

```
struct AppConfig {
    bool myoption1 {false};
};

void process_config(int argc, char * argv[], AppConfig & config) {
    // ...
    po::parse_config_file("config.cfg", config_file_options);
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that this interface doesn't provide a way to inject config file contents, so I thought about passing in a callback that `process_config()` can call in order to return a `basic_istream<charT>` that it can pass to `po::parse_config_file()`. That way, the tests can pass in a callback that simply provides a `std::istringstream` (a sub-class of the `basic_istream` template) with the config file contents preloaded, and the production client can pass in a simple callback that simply opens the specified file on disk and returns the corresponding istream.

To that end I created this:

```
template <typename funcF>
void process_config(int argc, char * argv[], AppConfig & config, funcF get_istream) {

    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description config_file_options;
    config_file_options.add_options() /* ... */;

    auto istr_up = get_istream("config.cfg");
    auto & istr = *istr_up.get();
    po::parse_config_file(istr, config_file_options);
}
```

Then in production code, I can use this to return the ifstream from the config file:

```
auto make_config_istream(const std::string & s) {
    return std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>(s.c_str());
}
```

And in the test code I can use this to return the config file contents from a string defined in the test:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::basic_istream<char>> make_istream(const std::string & s) {
    return std::make_unique<std::istringstream>(s);
}

process_config(0, nullptr, config,
               [](const std::string &){ return make_istream("foo=1\nbar=2");} );
```

This seems to compile and execute as I'd expect. However it seems a bit clunky because of the ignored `const std::string &` that has to be present for the lambda signature to match the `process_config` template, so I attempted to add this additional helper function to hide it away:

```
auto make_config(const std::string & config) {
    // the std::string parameter is ignored:
    return [config](const std::string &) { return make_istream(config); };
}
```

And then change the test code to:

```
process_config(0, nullptr, config, make_config("foo=1\nbar=2"));
```

This syntax will meet my requirements.

Note that I'm passing back the `istream` objects within unique pointers. I'm not 100% sure that is the right way to do it, but because the default constructor for istream is disabled, I can't pass them around by value, so it seems I have to allocate them on the heap and pass them around by pointer.

## Questions

Thank you for reading this far. My questions are:

1. Is it appropriate / best-practice to return the newly constructed `istream` on the heap, via the use of a `unique_ptr`? Is there a better way to do this?
2. Is the approach of dereferencing the unique_ptr to gain access to a reference to the `istream` correct using `auto & istr = *istr_up.get()`? This smells bad to me.
3. Is using a templated `process_config` function the best way to handle the types involved in the `get_istream` parameter? Is there a better way to do it with `auto`?
4. Lastly, is there a better approach to this entire issue?

Comment: I/O streams are movable since C++11 so heap-allocation isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I thought that might be true, but when I tried to `std::move` the return value the compiler complained that I was returning a reference to a locally allocated object. If I don't use `std::move` and try to pass by value then I get an error that the default copy constructor is disabled.

Comment: If you don't want template, you might use erase type `std::function<std::istream(const std::string&)>` or custom interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate / best-practice to return the newly constructed istream on the heap, via the use of a unique_ptr? Is there a better way to do this?

`basic_istream` is movable, you don't need `unique_ptr`:

```
auto make_config_istream(const std::string & s) {
    return std::ifstream(s);
}

auto make_istream(const std::string & s) {
    return std::istringstream(s);
}

template <typename funcF>
void process_config(int argc, char * argv[], AppConfig & config, funcF get_istream) {

    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description config_file_options;
    config_file_options.add_options() /* ... */;

    auto istr = get_istream("config.cfg");
    po::parse_config_file(istr, config_file_options);
}
```

The rest can stay as is.

> Is the approach of dereferencing the unique_ptr to gain access to a reference to the istream correct using auto & istr = *istr_up.get()? This smells bad to me.

It is correct, but unnecessary complicated because `auto & istr = *istr_up;` does the same. You can also use `istr_up` as if it was a raw pointer (i.e. with `->` and `*`).

> Is using a templated process_config function the best way to handle the types involved in the get_istream parameter? Is there a better way to do it with auto?

Yes that is the proper way to do it, but requires `parse_config` to be moved into a header shared by all translation units using it, or otherwise extra care needs to be taken to correctly explicitly instantiate where necessary.

---

The usage of `process_config` seems too complicated to me, why not:

```
process_config(0, nullptr, config,
    [](auto){return std::istringstream("foo=1\nbar=2");})
```

and

```
process_config(0, nullptr, config,
    [](auto s){return std::ifstream(s);})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the feedback. I don't mind your suggested changes to the usage of `process_config`, I was just trying to reduce the verbosity of it a little since it will be repeated many times throughout the suite of tests.